# Cancel iOS Local Notification in didReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have scheduled some notification, in some cases i need to cancel notification when this notification is fired and call method `didReceiveLocalNotification`  . My code is here

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        for notification in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications! {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
        }
}
```

but is not working, are there any ideas how  to cancel notification at this moment?

in other word i want to receive only notification event, no sound no notification on status bar

Comment: You want to cancel a notification that just fired? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry if question is ambiguous, i want to cancel notification sound and event on status bar

Comment: UILocalNotification are made to alert the user if he/she does not have the app open. You can set a custom sound for the notification (try specifying a file that does not exist) and and empty message but I think you will still get the bar.

What are you trying to achieve with this notification? Is it meant for the user? It does not look like. If so you are using the wrong tool.

Comment: i want to schedule event in background mode

Comment: That's not the way to do it. UILocalNotifications are meant for user interaction not for scheduling work for you app. If you are not using one of the background modes (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html ) your app will not run in the background, it will be suspended once the user exits and it will do no work past that point.

Comment: Sorry, no background mode. so , i use geofensis , i want to receive event when user enter in geofeces and stay here specific time

Comment: form iPhone 5S on you can you CoreLocation CLVisit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLVisit_class/ to determine where the user has been in the past (requires permission). If you are using the GPS you can subscribe to significant location changes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Comment: Consider closing this question and asking another one more relevant to your problem. To answer this one obviously you can't cancel a UILocalNotification that just fired because it's too late. Also relate to your previous comments in short there is not way to schedule work in the future if your app in not the foreground app and if you don't use a background mode or a sever to send you a notification to wake your app up.